# Как проверить, есть ли слово в значениях словаря?

Tags: python

Есть словарь:

```
a = {0: ['убрать','удалить'],
     1: ['добавить','прибавить'],
     2: ['изменить', 'исправить']}
```

Как проверить, есть ли слово "убрать" в словаре и вернуть его ключ?

Comment: `next(k for k, v in a.items() if 'убрать' in v)`.

Comment: В next надо добавить параметр None, чтобы не давало ошибку при отсутствии значения. Этот вариант хорош, если задача требуется редко. Если нужно часто надо создать "обратный" словарь `a_rev = {w: k for k, words in a.items() for w in words}`

Answer (score 0):

вот еще способ, не скажу что самый эффективный, но вроде рабочий:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {0: ['убрать','удалить'],
     1: ['добавить','прибавить'],
     2: ['изменить', 'исправить']}

q = 'изменить'  # слово для проверки

df = pd.DataFrame(a.values(),index=a.keys()).stack().to_frame().droplevel(1)
df[df[0]==q][0].to_dict()
```

вывод:

```
{2: 'изменить'}
```